# Htaccess redirect from one url to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect URLs that end with **domain.com/acme1/list-all-products.html**, **domain.com/acme2/list-all-products.html** etc to **domain.com/acme1.html**, **domain.com/acme2.html**. I tried adding these lines to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^list-all-products.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

but I see no effect. I know I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

The query string isn't what you want. you don't need the rewritecond:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/list-all-products.html$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```